# RequestPath in UseStaticFiles and the tilde character

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After using

```
app.UseStaticFiles(requestPath: "/static")
```

,
path generated through

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/global.css"/>
```

is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/global.css"/>
```

instead of the expected

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/global.css"/>
```

How may the path generation logic of the tilde character be updated to use `requestPath`?

Answer (score 0):

The tilde is used to refer to the application root. For example, if your application is configured to have a different path base (using `UsePathBase()`), then that path base is considering for incoming requests when you use dynamic paths using the tilde character.

The character is however not a shortcut to reach the static files root. It is completely valid to use a application-relative path using the tilde to reach a non-static path, for example if you have some other middleware that can answer requests.

Conceptually, it also wouldn’t be possible for the tilde to automatically pick up where the static files are, for multiple reasons:

- When you do `app.UseStaticFiles(requestPath: …)`, that path is only stored locally within the static file middleware. The information about that root does not reach outside.
- Technically, you can totally use multiple static file middlewares, by calling `UseStaticFiles()` multiple times with different configurations. That way, there would be no way to properly know which static file root you are referring to.

I would generally recommend you to keep the static files middleware at the default. That way, static files like the `favicon.ico`, that benefits from being at the root, can be still served correctly. If you want your files to be within a subpath, consider just creating a subfolder within the `wwwroot` instead. That way, you will also get proper IntelliSense when you use the tilde within your Razor views.

Comment: In this case, perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1 contains inaccurate information, namely "The tilde character ~/ points to webroot.".

Comment: Technically, the quote would be *“In the preceding code, the tilde character ~/ points to webroot”* which would be correct because the preceding code also shows an unmodified `UseStaticFiles()` call. But yeah, that could be improved. You can leave feedback for the docs at the bottom of the page and ask for that to be clarified.